# LER XML EM ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Boas, estou a trabalhar num projeto em que consiste ler ficheiros XML, mas estou com um problema.
O ficheiro XML  tem varios subchilds.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<products>
<product>
    <id>100</id>
    <name>Ball</name>
    <price>15</price>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
<description>
    <comment>aaa</comment>
</description>
</product>
</products>
```

Este é um exemplo de um XML que eu tenho. Ora eu consigo ler o id, name, price e a quantity mas quando chega à parte de ler a description já não consigo.

```
private List<Product> ProcessImport(string path)
    {
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(path);
        List<Product> products = xDocument.Descendants("product").Select
            (p => new Product()
            {
               Id = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("id").Value),
               Name=p.Element("name").Value,
               Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("quantity").Value),
               Price = Convert.ToDecimal(p.Element("price").Value),




            }).ToList();
        foreach(var product in products)
        {
            var productInfo = db.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id.Equals(product.Id));
            if(productInfo != null)
            {
                productInfo.Id = product.Id;
                productInfo.Name = product.Name;
                productInfo.Quantity = product.Quantity;
                productInfo.Price = product.Price;


            }
            else
            {
                db.Products.Add(product);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return products;
    }
```

Eu fiz este código em c#. O que é que eu preciso de acrescentar mais aqui?
Será que tenho que criar outro Controller para ler a description.
Agradeço desde já a ajuda!! (já estou a tentar fazer isto há mais de uma semana!!)

Comment: reflita a estrutura do xml em classes e você vai entender como manipular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se é isso que você está querendo mas achei bem simples, basta você navegar no elemento "description".

```
List<Product> products = xDocument.Descendants("product").Select
            (p => new Product()
            {
               Id = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("id").Value),
               Name=p.Element("name").Value,
               Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(p.Element("quantity").Value),
               Price = Convert.ToDecimal(p.Element("price").Value),
               Comment = p.Element("description").Element("comment").Value
            }).ToList();
```

Coloquei um exemplo no [Dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DX2jpB) e republiquei aqui também [Github](https://github.com/rafaelchagasb/answers-stackoverflow/tree/master/pt.stackoverflow.com/dotnet/451007)